# Set a value in a Datagridviewcomboboxcell in datagridview when i click a cell in other datagridview in the same winForm in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Datagridview in the same WinForm, in one I have a column that is of the Datagridviewcomboboxcell type with their assigned values from a list. I would like to be able to set a current value in the combobox cell when I select a value in a cell of the second datagridview. The current value of the combobox will be equal to the selected value.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the rows are equal for both DataGridView controls, then you can set the cell value on the `CellValueChanged` event:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnName"].Value = 
        dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
}
```

There will be necessary to add some guards to avoid exceptions when e.g. index is out of range.

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit enough in my question. The CellValueChanged event does not work for me because the elements of the second datagridview are not in a combobox, they are elements of type TexboxCell. The idea is that when I click on a row for example, the element of cell 1 in the first datagridview is equal to the element of cell 1 in the second datagridview, of course the possible elements in the rows of the second datagriview will always be equal to those of the collection contained in the DatagridviewComboboxCell.